# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^n}{(1+3)(1+3^2)(1+3^3)\ldots (1+3^n)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

It is visible that the result is 0, but I can't calculate it.
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^n}{(1+3)(1+3^2)(1+3^3)\ldots (1+3^n)}$

It occurred to me to express it as a product and take a ratio test, but I'm not sure

Comment: What if you divide both the numerator & denominator by $3^n$, specifically $(1 + 3^n)$ in the denominator?

Comment: This is not allowed

Comment: Ignore all terms in the denominator except the last two.

Comment: +1 for @Paul123's comment which gives the simplest approch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{3^n}{(1+3)(1+3^2)\dots(1+3^n)}\leq\frac{3^n}{(1+3^{n-1})(1+3^n)}$$
and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n}{(1+3^{n-1})(1+3^n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+3^{n-1}}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n}{1+3^n}=0\cdot 1=0$$
Hence by the squeeze theorem our original limit is $0$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough? $\frac{3^n}{(1+3)(1+3^2)\dots(1+3^n)}\leq\frac{3^n}{(1+3^n)}$ ?

Comment: @martin19875 That only proves the limit, if it exists, is at most $1$. You really need the $1+3^{n-1}$ factor in the denominator too.

Comment: I can see it, thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\begin{align}0≤\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^n}{(1+3)(1+3^2)(1+3^3)\ldots (1+3^n)}≤\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^n}{3×3^2\ldots 3^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac {3^n}{3^{\frac {n(n+1)}{2}}}=0\end{align}$$

Comment: May I ask how did you get to  $3*(n(n+1)/2)$

Comment: @martin19875 of course. Just take arithmetic sequence on the power $1+2+3+\cdots n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: So you stick out 3, if I understand it.

Comment: but shouldn't it be more of a geometric sequence?

Comment: @martin19875 $$3^1+3^2+\cdots 3^n≠3^1×3^2×\cdots 3^n$$

Comment: I can already see it, I read it on my mobile phone as 3*something instead of 3^something :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(n)=\frac{3^n}{(1+3)(1+3^2)\cdots(1+3^n)}
=\frac{\frac{3^n}{3^1 3^2 \cdots 3^n}}{\frac{1+3^1}{3^1}\frac{1+3^2}{3^2}\cdots\frac{1+3^n}{3^n}}\\
=\frac{\frac{3^n}{3^{\frac{n(n+1)}2}}}{(1+3^{-1})(1+3^{-2})\cdots(1+3^{-n})}
=\frac{2\cdot 3^{-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}}{\left(-1;\frac{1}{3}\right)_{n+1}}
$$
in terms of a [$q$-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) in the denominator.
For large $n$ this denominator approaches a constant,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-1;\frac{1}{3}\right)_{n+1}
= \left(-1;\frac{1}{3}\right)_{\infty}
\approx 3.129868037134023\ldots,
$$
in Mathematica,

```
    QPochhammer[-1, 1/3] // N
```

and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$.